# Why does this not modify for compliance?

Tags: java, string

```
public static String modifyForCompliance(String header) {
    String modHeader = header;
    for (int i = 0; i < replacement.length; i++) {
        modHeader.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(replacement[i][0]), Pattern.quote(replacement[i][1]));
        System.out.println(modHeader);
    }
    return modHeader;
}
```

So above I have this method, which should change all of the [i][0] args in the array below into the [i][1] args. This is supposed to allow the string to be put in for a file name. However, the print I get is posted below, and you will notice it does not match what the method is trying to do...
Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Starting string:

```
Game <UUID: a1ddc565-8205-45e6-9c9e-4855ee271c0b>
```

Array:

```
public static final String[][] replacement = new String[][] {{" ", "_"}, {"\\", "(backslash)"}, {"/", "(forwardslash)"}, {":", "="}, {"*", "(asterisk)"}, {"?", "(q-mark)"}, {"\"", "(quotation)"}, {"<", "("}, {">", ")"}, {"|", "(bar)"}};
```

Prints:

```
2013-09-14 11:15:21 [INFO] Game <UUID: a1ddc565-8205-45e6-9c9e-4855ee271c0b>
2013-09-14 11:15:21 [INFO] Game <UUID: a1ddc565-8205-45e6-9c9e-4855ee271c0b>
2013-09-14 11:15:21 [INFO] Game <UUID: a1ddc565-8205-45e6-9c9e-4855ee271c0b>
2013-09-14 11:15:21 [INFO] Game <UUID: a1ddc565-8205-45e6-9c9e-4855ee271c0b>
2013-09-14 11:15:21 [INFO] Game <UUID: a1ddc565-8205-45e6-9c9e-4855ee271c0b>
2013-09-14 11:15:21 [INFO] Game <UUID: a1ddc565-8205-45e6-9c9e-4855ee271c0b>
2013-09-14 11:15:21 [INFO] Game <UUID: a1ddc565-8205-45e6-9c9e-4855ee271c0b>
2013-09-14 11:15:21 [INFO] Game <UUID: a1ddc565-8205-45e6-9c9e-4855ee271c0b>
2013-09-14 11:15:21 [INFO] Game <UUID: a1ddc565-8205-45e6-9c9e-4855ee271c0b>
2013-09-14 11:15:21 [INFO] Game <UUID: a1ddc565-8205-45e6-9c9e-4855ee271c0b>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings are immutable, so you have to reassign `modHeader`:

```
modHeader = modHeader.replaceAll(...);
```

By the way, you might want to use [`replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) instead, since you're not dealing with regular expressions. i.e.:

```
modHeader = modHeader.replace(replacement[i][0], replacement[i][1]);
```

That'll get rid of the annoying `Pattern.quote()` calls.

Comment: thats what i was going to say :D

Answer (score 0):

`String#replaceAll()` returns the `String` with the updated value and does not affect the `String` you are passing.

*Strings are Immutable in Java.*

```
modHeader = modHeader.replaceAll(..);
```